# Get user location by ip used online service with php cURL and json

Tags: php, json, curl, location, ip

Today i have some php cURL code that must show to user his loacation like: ip, country, city it have.. And if the user is bot - do nothing. So, i do it like this, but it's not working properly. Only ip is shown and nothing else.. Please help.. And let the power be with you.. Thank to all for help.

```
<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$apiurl = "https://api.2ip.ua/geo.json?ip=$ip";
//--
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$apiurl");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);
//--
curl_close ($ch);

//- **************-//
$pieces = explode('"', $contents);
$country = $pieces['7'];
$city = $pieces['11'];
$city2 = $pieces['13'];

echo "Your IP is :" . $ip  . " and country " .$country. " and city " .$city;


 ?>
```

Comment: Locations are not accurate, would it not make more sense to get the IP of the client and check it against the IP of the bot? What does `getBotList()` return?

Comment: @Jaquarh getBotList() check .txt file for bot USER_AGENT i need this to write all data from user to mySQL base and i want only real USER_AGENT... i cut off this part of script... sorry... i cut all not needed

Comment: So where is the code you're using to write this information to your database? This isn't a code writing service. Your question is unclear, what are you actually asking?

Comment: @Jaquarh... the question not in this case..... ))) i edit a code...

Comment: @Jaquarh... It is not my fault that you cannot read. Why do you need my code writing data to the database, if the question is that I need to output the data received from the user_agent (not the data from the database) to a normal page and the user should see this. That's why I posted only part of the code that does not work, everything else works fine!... I don't need that you or anyone else write me a full code, i did it bymyself if you can't see... but i don't understand why it's not working!!!... And why you clicking minus on my question, not my fault that you can't read!

Comment: I can read, your question was not a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) prior to you editing it and the question was unclear due to the lack of proper English.

Comment: @Jaquarh.... may be! ... But ... my problem is still not solved ...

Comment: @Jaquarh... and yes i have bad english because my native language is Ukrainian

Comment: `curl_exec($ch)` returns false - maybe check the documentation for the API ensuring you do not need to add a user agent header or authorisation to use the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use explode!, the answer of the api is a JSON, instead you got to do this:

```
$data = json_decode($contents, true);
$country = $data['country'];
$city = $data['city'];
```

and so on for any other field you need.

BTW you can also improve the IP detection with this code that support multiple detection with ipv4 and ipv6 support

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HOST'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HOST'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    } else {
        $host = '';
    }
    $ip = str_replace("::ffff:","",$ip);//::ffff:127.127.127.127 en caso de jugo ipv6
```

Regards and vote up

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use explode, use json_decode instead and then there is something wrong with the SSL-Certificate of your API so use http instead.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$apiurl = "http://api.2ip.ua/geo.json?ip=";
$contents = file_get_contents($apiurl . $ip);
$json = json_decode($contents);
$country = $json->country;
$city = $json->city;
echo "Your IP is :" . $ip  . " and country " . $country . " and city " . $city;
```